# VirtualBox Ubuntu Guest Additions not installing : modprobe vboxsf failed

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, linux-kernel

I just installed this software off virtual box, i downloaded the ISO off the official ubuntu website, was the lastest LTS.

I attempted to install Guest Additions using the 'Insert Guest Additions CD Image".
Result:

```
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 5.2.0 Guest Additions for Linux........
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Removing installed version 5.2.0 of VirtualBox Guest Additions...
Copying additional installer modules ...
Installing additional modules ...
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions 
kernel modules.
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Look at /var/log/vboxadd-setup.log to find 
out what went wrong
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Running kernel modules will not be replaced 
until the system is restarted
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Starting.
VirtualBox Guest Additions: modprobe vboxsf failed
Press Return to close this window...
```

Inside the /var/log/vboxadd-setup.log:

ERROR:

```
Kernel configuration is invalid.
include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.
Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.
```

Full version of log file can be found here [[?]](https://pastebin.com/iiFB57u1)

Comment: I'm having the same problems for Ubuntu 17.10 . It's strange, because the logfile has errors, saying that certain files exist, but those files actually do exist

Comment: This answer on askubuntu may have the solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/846142

Comment: Note that the `modprobe vboxsf failed` line is actually a red herring according to [this ticket](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/17189#comment:3): _The message "modprobe vboxsf failed" is just cosmetic, not a real problem, but I agree that it is confusing and should be fixed._

Answer (score 31):

Ok, so this is a known problem. Instead of using the image provided by virtualbox you should just download it trough aptitute `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms` and if you need the headers download this `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-virtual` instead of the classic `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`.

Cheers

Edit: Changed the `{}` for `()` as pointed by @Abdelouahab.

Comment: Where did you find this solution? I did try installing `virtualbox-guest-dkms`. That gave me a shared clipboard, but no ability to share folders.

Comment: @Justin This did it for me on Lubuntu 14.04, a couple of months ago.

Comment: there is a tiny error, use `$(VAR)` instead of `$(VAR)` when you want to excecute a code as a variable

Comment: So what do you mean by "known problem"? What is the problem? Is somebody working on it? Do you have a link to an issue somewhere? Or did you just mean that you happened to find other questions about the same thing?

Comment: @thoni56 the ticket is https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/17189 which says it is fixed altho I got this today...

Comment: @thoni56 It's indeed a known problem, with a lot of possible solutions yet they only seem to work on certian conditions. If you follow trought both error logs, when installing guest additions from the iso it will tell you, you lack software, or dependencies. Once your sort that out it will come with other error and so on. Easiest way to solve this is trought Aptitude.

Comment: I would not recommend installing `virtualbox-guest-dkms` - that version may not be compatible with your Virtualbox version. You can get the proper `VBoxGuestAdditions.iso` file at https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.2.6/. Also I would not recommend  `linux-headers-virtual` unless you are running `linux-image-virtual` - see https://askubuntu.com/questions/175495/what-are-the-differences-between-linux-generic-linux-server-and-linux-virtual-k
Hopefully this bug will be resolved; related difficulties reported at https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=85186

Comment: Following the above steps and then increasing the video memory in the settings worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

open the terminal and run `sudo reboot`.

then try to install again via devices -> Insert Guest Additions CD Image.

worked for me.

Comment: I rebooted and tried again - still failed (got an error `Unable to insert the virtual optical disk... VBoxGuestAdditions.iso into the machine...`) [This blog post](http://nanxiao.me/en/install-virtualbox-guest-additions/) seems to help

Comment: "worked for me" is the kind of answer that marks someone as unhelpful and a poor listener.

Answer (score 4):

in Ubuntu 16.04 I had to reboot the O.S. before installing virtualbox-guest-additions in order to load the correct kernel

Comment: Yea, got the error, but the latest 6.0.0 directory was under opt, and upon reboot lsmod / modinfo showed that correct version too.

Answer (score 2):

A similar problem can occur with VirtualBox 5.2.18 and Linux guests, including Fedora 28, that are running kernel 4.18: Building the Guest Additions will fail with the same error message, "modprobe vboxsf failed", and no vboxsf module output to the /lib/modules folder.

The solution (for now) is to [download](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds#Developmentsnapshots) and install the latest development snapshot of the Guest Additions, version 5.2.97, as explained in [a ticket on the VirtualBox site](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/17981).

The symptom is messages like these appearing in one of the log files written to /var/log by the build process:

```
/tmp/vbox.0/utils.c: In function ‘sf_init_inode’:
/tmp/vbox.0/utils.c:165:28: error: passing argument 1 of ‘sf_ftime_from_timespec’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
     sf_ftime_from_timespec(&inode->i_atime, &info->AccessTime);
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/vbox.0/utils.c:53:53: note: expected ‘struct timespec *’ but argument is of type ‘struct timespec64 *’
 static void sf_ftime_from_timespec(struct timespec *tv, RTTIMESPEC *ts)
```

Note the build process can output *multiple* log files, which means looking at only the latest one (as the message it outputs suggests) is not a reliable way of diagnosing problems. In my case, trying to install the Guest Additions on a headless Fedora server failed with /var/log/vboxadd-setup.log containing only the line

```
Could not find the X.Org or XFree86 Window System, skipping.
```

The key was to examine the file /var/log/vboxadd-setup.log.1, generated at the same time, which contained the actual error messages from the build, shown above.

Comment: Very helpful comments. In my case, I ran into an incompatibility of the 4.20 kernel with virtualbox 4.2.22. It should get fixed in the next release: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/18183?cversion=0&cnum_hist=2

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04.

In the comments to the question there are a bit confusing but useful links.

Same exact problem solved by purging 5.2.8 and installing 5.1.34_Ubuntu r121010 from repo:

```
$ grep virtualbox /etc/apt/sources.list
deb https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib
```

Installation of guest additions completed without "VirtualBox Guest Additions: modprobe vboxsf failed" error.

```
sudo purge virtualbox*
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian $(lsb_release -sc) contrib"
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

Thanks to Justin for the link https://askubuntu.com/a/846142
but had to use

```
sudo apt-get install VirtualBox
```

rather than

```
sudo apt-get install VirtualBox-*
```

cause the last one gave me a whole mess of tricky unmet dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded today the Ubuntu 16.04 ISO file and installed it. I also have the latest VirtualBox version.

Trying to install the Guest Additions, I faced the error mentioned originally.

I just did what others said before... with the guest additions ISO still inserted on the VM, I ran:

```
sudo reboot
```

After logging in again, I went to the ISO folder:

```
/media/<ubuntu_username>/VBox_GAs_5.2.8
```

Then I executed:

```
sudo ./autorun.sh
```

The installation finalized without issues.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem both on Ubuntu & Windows host (Lubuntu Guest), and in both cases, this is what I did.

1. Unmount the guest additions CD
2. Shut down virtual machine.
3. Download the appropriate guest additions CD from Virtualbox website. In my case, it was 5.2 Link:https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/
4. Go to settings>Storage, and under **"controller: ID"** option, add an optical drive with the guest additions CD
5. Reboot your virtual machine.
6. Once the machine is booted, click Devices>Insert Guest Additions CD image
7. Cd to the optical drive /media/username/VBox_GAs_5.2
8. Run sudo sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run